# Bash Loop add more to loops

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I tried doing `while` as well, but it doesn't seem to work with Centos version 7. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm just trying to add one back to the loop if it does not meet my greater than logic. Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

```
clips=200
for (( i=0 ; i<clips ; i++ ))
if(("$cutlength">8)); then
echo "good"
else 
echo "redo, adding one back to loop"
i=$(($i-1))
fi
```

Comment: Where is `cutlength` being set and what is purpose of `i=$(($i-1))` ?

Comment: @anubhava `cutlength` is just another number... `i=$(($i-1))` i want the loop to redo so I get my complete 200 `good` echos...

Comment: A for loop starts with a `do` and ends with a `done`.

Comment: What your script prints? When I tried to execute it then I realized the `do` and `done` keywords are missing and the `cutlength` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if other things are ok:

```
clips=200
for (( i=0 ; i<clips ; i++ )); do
    if (( cutlength > 8 )); then
        echo "good"
    else 
        echo "redo, adding one back to loop"
        ((i--))
    fi
done
```

Comment: thanks buddy! works great... other things are great... this one works